# How can I insert a token into reCaptcha when I solve it with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, recaptcha

I received the token for reCaptcha from a paid service. Now I try to pass this token into reCaptcha form.

```py
self.browser.get('https://visa.vfsglobal.com/rus/en/fra/login')

self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-input-0').send_keys('login')
self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-input-1').send_keys('password')

self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.removeProperty('display');")
self.browser.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML = '{code}'")
self.browser.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="none";')

submit_btn = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'mat-focus-indicator')]")
submit_btn.click()
```

But I receive the "Mandatory field cannot be left blank" error.
Also, I tried this code:

```py
recaptcha_response_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="g-recaptcha-response"]')
self.browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{code}";', recaptcha_response_element)
```

And this one has the same result.
What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to run automated script on a visa issuing portal? This should be illegal and your IP is in risk of being restricted!

Comment: Thank you. I think it should be OK. I interact a lot with this site manually too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this approaches?

1. Set directly using element methods

```
recaptcha_response_element.set_attribute("value", code)
```

2. Set using JS only

```
self.browser.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").setAttribute("value", "{code}"')
```

3. Replace the raw value set by js "setAttribute"

```
self.browser.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value",arguments[1])',element, code)
```

For mandatory fields left blank, check if there is another field missing. Sometimes there's reflective data that are not fulfilled because page state manipulation can avoid triggering some listeners.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.
recaptcha_response_element.set_attribute("value", code) # doesn't work, WebElement has only get_attribute
self.browser.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").setAttribute("value", "{code}")') # gets "Mandatory field cannot be left blank"
self.browser.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value",arguments[1])', recaptcha_response_element, code) # gets "Mandatory field cannot be left blank"